# Get last value from incomplete observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

There is an incomplete observable which can have or not have a replay of n values. I would like to get the last value from it - or just the next one if there is none yet.

This works for first available value with `first()` and `take(1)` ([example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UEKVS23Hl7hvhGFaPezV?p=preview)):

```
possiblyReplayedIncomplteObservable.first().toPromise().then(val => ...);
```

But for the last value both `last()` and `takeLast(1)` wait for observable completion - not the desirable behaviour here.

How can this be solved? Is there a specific operator for that?

Comment: Can you not use another replayed observable - that uses the same source - that has a single replayed value rather than N values? That's the behaviour your are looking for, right?

Answer (score 4):

I had a solution for `ReplaySubject(2)` that 'drains' the sequence to get the latest element and if the sequence is empty simply takes the last element, yet, it was cumbersome and did not scale well (for example, if you decide to increase the replay size to 3). I then remembered that Replay/Behavior subjects tend to be hard to manage when they are piped. The simplest solution to that is to create a 'shadow' sequence and pipe your ReplaySubject into it (instead of creating it by transformation/operation on your ReplaySubject), hence:

```
var subject$ = new Rx.ReplaySubject(3);
var lastValue$ = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
subject$.subscribe(lastValue$); // short hand for subject$.subscribe(v => lastValue$.next(v))

lastValue$.take(1).toPromise().then(...);
```

========== Old solutions, ignoring the ReplaySubject(2) =================

After reading the comment below, the correct code is:

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(possiblyReplayedIncomplteObservable).take(1).subscribe(...)
```

and not

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(possiblyReplayedIncomplteObservable).subscribe(...)
```

This is due to the fact the promise is a "one time" observable. I think the `toPromise()` code resolves the result only on completion.

The `take(1)` will not affect your original stream since it operates on the new stream which is created by `combineLatest`.

And actually, the simplest way is:

```
possiblyReplayedIncomplteObservable.take(1).toPromise().then(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. combineLatest would be good solution, but I'm having problems with it. It returns an array, and it can be easily fixed. But it creates incomplete observable too, toPromise won't work as well ([see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MYXA77bKSodmCNiyAFik)).

Comment: Sadly, it looks like it's not that simple. `take(1)` will take the first value from replay ('two' instead of 'three' here http://plnkr.co/edit/MzrwhL1A2YEA0wApfKRy). So it doesn't differ from `possiblyReplayedIncomplteObservable.take(1)` in this respect.

Comment: Ouch, it is a  replaySubject. Looking into it

Comment: But I'm confused, you said "get the last value or the next one if there is none yet", so where is the problem? Or alternatively, why is it a ReplaySubject(2)?

Comment: I would expect the last available value at this moment (`three`) if the observable is not empty. Or just wait for the first available value if there are no values (`one` if `toPromise` goes before the values are pushed to the subject). Hope this description is clear enough.

Comment: It is. What fails it is that your ReplaySubject is of length 2, is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: That's interpolation of two cases, it may possibly look confusing. I need to cover 3 cases for `toPromise` chain - completed observable with n values (e.g. `Observable.of`, something where `last()` could help), incomplete observable with 1 value replayed (e.g. `publishReplay(1)`) and existing values, incomplete observable with no value replayed and no values yet.  I've merged the first two into ReplaySubject(n) for brevity.